# Are ArcadeDB & OrientDB both scalable?

Tags: orientdb

Are ArcadeDB & OrientDB both scalable horizontally & vertically?

Answer (score 2):

OrientDB and ArcadeDB are both scalable. While OrientDB provides a multi-master replication + sharding, the implementation of the sharding was never completed, so you should consider having multiple nodes with the entire database on all of them. While this is usually not an issue (HDD or SDD is cheap), for huge databases, such as tens of TB or more, this could be an issue.

ArcadeDB uses a more conventional Leader/Follower (RAFT) replication approach. The main reason is to reach rock solidity in a short time, while with OrientDB after many years, there are still unresolved issues with replication, partially caused by the complexity of having an ACID multi-master DBMS.

OrientDB doesn't scale well vertically because of the heavy usage of RAM and Garbage Collector. ArcadeDB is much more efficient in terms of CPU and RAM usage with zero-copy low-level buffer management that has a minimal impact on the Garbage Collector.

ArcadeDB is also much safer than OrientDB because it uses a synchronous WAL (Journal), while OrientDB has an asynchronous WAL that can lead to potential loss of transactions even after they are committed.

Last but not least, OrientDB has lost official support (from SAP) and the community has not been active for years. ArcadeDB instead has a very active development with at least one release per month.

You can see ArcadeDB as the evolution of OrientDB.

Disclaimer: I am the original author of both OrientDB and now ArcadeDB